# Capture AdvancedDataGrid column reordering

Tags: apache-flex, events, advanceddatagrid

I am trying to preserve the order, width, and visibility of columns in my advanceddatagrid. I've managed to get visibility with a click event on the TableColumnFilter and width by having the advanceddatagrid listen for a stretch event, but I can't find any event that will capture when a column has been moved.

At least not reliably. I tried AdvancedDataGridEvent.HEADER_DRAG_OUTSIDE and AdvancedDataGridEvent.HEADER_DROP_OUTSIDE, but those only fire when I drag a column to the edge of the AdvancedDataGrid.

So is there a way to capture when a user makes any change in the arrangement of columns in the AdvancedDataGrid? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is the "headerShift" event.